# Compare bits to a certain integer n in c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

If I have to compare some bits to a certain integer `n`, how do I do it?
For example: I need to see if the bits `a[3:0]` are greater than `n`.

So far I have this (and I know it doesn't work):

```c
while( ((a >> 0) & 1) > n );
```

I'm new to this and my English its not great so if I don't explain myself well I'm sorry, I'll try my best.

Comment: `if(a & 7 > n)`? Do you need to slice a certain bit span from the middle of an int, pretend it's a standalone int of its own, and compare that int to something?

Comment: @GSerg exactly.